# Firebase native plugin with push notifications is not working

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have tried to use [**Firebase native plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) to send push notifications.But it is not working (not getting a message to the real device).Can you tell me how to do that?

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(platform: Platform, private firebase: Firebase) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.firebase.getToken()
            .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));

 this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
            .subscribe(res => {
                if (res.tap) {
                    // background mode
                    console.log("background");
                    console.log(res);
                    alert(res);
                } else if (!res.tap) {
                    // foreground mode
                    console.log("foreground");
                    console.log(res);
                    alert(res);
                }
            });

      });
}
```

After the above implementation, I have tried to send push notification using `User Segment` on firebase compose message console.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean not working? Did you install the plugin? Did you configure firebase for your app?

Comment: Yes.Those are basic things no.Not working means not getting message to the real device @naomi

Comment: I have implemented Analytics with this plugin and it is working fine.The problem is with the Push notifications. @naomi

Comment: You need to call the `onNotificationOpen` to get notification data in a callback https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/#onNotificationOpen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There could be different reasons for push notifications not work. I provided a set of steps to follow in order to implement push notifications. Take a look maybe you have missed something.

Steps to implement push notifications in Ionic app (for android):

1. Create a new [firebase project](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/)

**Note:** The Firebase `package name` must be identical to the app `id` in the
`config.xml`.

2. Download the `google-services.json` file and put it in the root directory of your app.
3. Add the android platform `$ ionic platform add android` (if you don't have it yet)
4. Install the firebase plugin `$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase`.

**Note:** You should install the plugin after you have placed the `google-services.json`file in your project - because this file is copied into the platform directory during installation.

5. Install [ionic-native firebase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) package and implement the [`onNotificationOpen`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/#onNotificationOpen) method.
6. Add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   buildscript {
   // ...
       dependencies {
           // ...
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
       }
   }

   //....

   dependencies {
       // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
       // ...
       compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
       compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
   }
   ```
7. Build your app on an Android device `$ ionic build android`
8. Test push notifications. You could use [this](https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/) free firebase notifications sender.

**Note:** The API key is the one found in the Cloud Messaging Tab called `Legacy server key` in your firebase project.
Also if you're sending the notification to a specific topic, you need to first subscribe to this topic using the [subscribe](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/#subscribe) method.

Comment: Oh..Such a Great help.I'll try your steps and come back again.I definitely not followed those steps according to your order.One question, What about the way I have used `onNotificationOpen()` method.Is that correct? When I test this on the browser, I cannot run the app.After the `subscribe` line where it gives this run time error `Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available`.Do you know why?

Comment: Stack trace on `core.es5.js:1084` file `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.invoke (polyfills.js:3)`

Comment: cordova is only available in an app running on a device add `if(window.cordova)` before your code

Comment: Now it gives this error `Property 'cordova' does not exist on type 'Window'.`.How can I avoid it?

Comment: This `Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available` shows only with the `subscribe` method.No problem on other `promise` methods of the same plugin.Do you know why?

Comment: Try use `platform.is('cordova')` instead

Comment: Yes, Then no problem.But can you tell me why this different behavior with `promise` and `scbscribe` methods?

Comment: I have used this without `platform.is('cordova')` and no issues.Why ?`this.firebase.getToken()
   .then(token => console.log(`The token is ${token}`)) // save the token server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
   .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error));`.That one is `promise` method and no issues.Why?

Comment: I believe its something in the source code that makes the different. Did you get the notifications work?